# if else jQuery не работает

Tags: jquery

Добрый день, не пойму почему не срабатывает скрипт. Помогите пожалуйста

https://jsfiddle.net/3xd2wto5/

```
$('.language__link').on('mousemove',function(e){
    leftZ = 0;
    leftP = 50+"%";
    if(this.left > 0) {
        $(this).css({
            'position':'absolute',
            'left': leftZ
        });
    } else {
        $(this).css({
            'position':'absolute',
            'left': leftP
        });
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) У элемента нет свойства `left`, нужно `style.left`
2) Проверка некорректна, потому что когда вы вставите "50%", то это не будет больше нуля.

Пробуйте так:

```js
$('.language__link').on('mousemove', function(e) {
  leftZ = 0;
  leftP = "50%";
  if (this.style.left != 0 && this.style.left != '0px') {
    $(this).css({
      'position': 'absolute',
      'left': leftZ
    });
  } else {
    $(this).css({
      'position': 'absolute',
      'left': leftP
    });
  }

});
```

```css
.language__link {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 25px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="language__link">
  Text
</div>
```